# how to create a popup next to the mouse according to a container div

Tags: javascript, popup, position

I'm trying to display a div when mouse is over an element but the div is always inside the container div. Example (hover over any model at the bottom of this page) https://3dexport.com/
I've tried to get mouse position in the page and the mouse position inside the div but didn't work. Thanks in advance.

This is the main code I've used to display and hide a big div but the hidden process is not working though the alert is displayed (the black div is hidden by default)

```
$(".homeModelItem").mouseenter(function(){
var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    mouse.x = e.clientX || e.pageX;
    mouse.y = e.clientY || e.pageY;
    console.log(mouse.x);
    if(mouse.x<400 && mouse.x>0){
        $(".black").css({"left":"200px","display":"block"});
    }

});
});

$(".homeModelItem").mouseout(function(){
alert("xxx");
$(".black").css({"display":"none","left":"0"});
});
```

Comment: This is much better, but: hundreds of SO users have explained me the meaning of "not working", still I don't know what it exactly means. Can you please explain too ...

Comment: the first thing I want to do is to hide the black div if the cursor leaves any .homeModelItem div here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mhunwmuk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a new mousemove listener every time the mouse enters a `.homeModelItem`. In that handler you set `display: block` for `.black`, and this will override the hiding in mouseleave handler.

It looks like you want to position `.black` related to the currently hovered `.homeModelItem`. You can do it for example like this:

```
$(".homeModelItem").mouseenter(function (e) {
    $(e.target).append($('.black')); // Move the .black to the target element
    $(".black").css({
        display: "block"
    });
});

$(".homeModelItem").mouseleave(function (e) {
    $(".black").css({
        display: "none"
    });
});
```

Addition to `.homeModelItem` CSS:

```
position: relative;
```

and to `.black` CSS:

```
left: 100px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 100;
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhs390z8/2/).

If you'll need the mousemove somewhere, you can add it, but outside of any event handler (unles you will remove it in another handler).

Comment: fiddle updated it's so close to what I need http://jsfiddle.net/jhs390z8/3/ you can add it to your answer and I really appreciate it if you have a look at it if it needs any modifications. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Updating the answer according to your new fiddle would confuse future visitors, since that behavior is not described in the question. Anyway, considering you've a bunch of `.homeModelItem`s on your real page, you could check the [`nth-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) to reduce the event handlers and code.